# How to focus cursor on text box in php

Tags: php, xhtml

How to focus cursor on text box in php.
On error answer by user i want to focus the answer filed on load of page. so please suggest me...

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sub_con_page']))
{
//correct
}
else 
{
**//focus field**
}
```

Comment: This can't be done in PHP, as PHP is ONLY server-side.  It has to be done in javascript.  Although you could have PHP output the proper javascript that would focus on the field in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding javascript/jquery code inside the else part of the statement:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sub_con_page']))
{
//correct
}
else 
{ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ID_OF_TEXT_AREA_TO_FOCUS_HERE").focus();
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do this in javascript. if you use jquery then

```
$("input[type=text]:first").focus();
```